# Should I check for filesystem corruption?

Tags: linux-mint, filesystems, corruption

I have a Linux Mint laptop with a faulty charger and bad battery life, and sometimes it abruptly turns off without shutting down. I haven't noticed anything different, but should I check for corruption?

Comment: If you are using a journalling file system like ext3/4 or a few others (ext4 is the current default for most OS's) then it will detect on startup when it needs to do some kind of check.  You should not need to explicitly run a scan, but of course you can if it would put your mind at ease.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use it for storage that's for sure, scan disk checks take a lot of time so you better get faulty charger fixed before anything else, your laptop may work without the battery.

Comment: yeah there isn't anything important on there just wondering